# Как устанавливать самые свежие пакеты в Debian

Tags: linux, debian

Хостер моей VPS использует собственное зеркало с пакетами времён динозавров(2013-2014 год), а я хочу устанавливать самые свежие пакеты. Как мне это сделать? Какие репозитории поставить, чтобы, например, nginx у меня устанавливался не 1.6.2, а 1.10.1?

Comment: *Как мне это сделать?* — обсудить с хостером возможность установки тестируемой версии дистрибутива вместо стабильной.

Comment: какая версия debian у вас сейчас? (`cat /etc/debian_version`)

Comment: Оно конечно хорошо, только приготовься к тому, что всё сломается. Так что сделай бэкап или типа того. P.S. Систему релизов придумали не от нечего делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Официально поддерживаемый командой Debian способ выборочного обновления пакетов это [backports](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/Backports). В нём собраны пакеты более новых версий скомпилированные в среде старого дистрибутива. Будем считать к примеру, что ваш дистрибутив jessie. Вам нужно добавить или раскомментировать в `/etc/apt/sources.list` строку:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

При этом методе после `apt-get update` при обновлениях системы ничего не изменится, по прежнему будут предлагаться старые пакеты. Но если вам нужен более новый, его можно будет поставить указав релиз:

```
# apt-get -t jessie-backports install nginx
```

Cудя по сервису [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=nginx&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) на текущий момент в backports для jessie версия nginx тоже не самая новая - 1.9.10.

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы на Вашем VPS было всегда свежее ПО, нужно установить сторонний репозиторий, например: https://www.dotdeb.org/

Согласно [инструкции](https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) по использованию добавьте в ваш `/etc/apt/sources.list` строки вида:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
```

Comment: Прежде чем подключать ноыве репозитории, убедитесь, что ОС "времен динозавров" будет с ними корректно работать и что хостер поддерживает такие случаи. А то останетесь без сапорта и без хостинга разом.

Comment: Smithson согласен, для новый репо подтянет свой совместимости, а для старого нужны будут свои старые и из за этого может вызван конфликт, остается только ручками компилировать новое